# BootsrapButton in Listview no click event trigered

Tags: android, android-listview

i use this library https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap for buttons in android.

I have the button inside a listview element but onItemClick is not calling on selecting list item. Code below

ListView Element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#424242"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/Button_Sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-angle-right"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView OnItemCLick:

```
SamplesListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListView_Samples);
        SamplesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BootstrapButton Sample = (BootstrapButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Button_Sample);
                String Tokens[] = Sample.getText().toString().split("\n");
                if(Tokens!=null){
                    GlobalActivity.Sample = Tokens[0];
                    GlobalActivity.MeasuresNumber = (Tokens[1].split(BLANKSPACE))[2];
                    ShowAlicoDetails();
                }
            }
        });
```

Also i use fragment.
Can you help me to get ItemClick called?

Comment: Is the click event triggered when you use a normal Button in place of the BootstrapButton?

Comment: yes... only on bootstrap not..

Answer (score 0):

try giving the attributes

```
btnRef.setFocusable(false);
btnRef.setClickable(false);
btnRef.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

programmatically

Since its a custom class, I used to face problems like this, the attributes given in xml used to get ignored, this is because may be they change the properties in onDraw()?